# how to echo a node value (not atribute)

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodes

I've got this problem:

This is my .xml

```
<listado>
    <sucursal> //first sucursal
        <idSuc>1</idSuc>
        <nombre>Peru</nombre>
    </sucursal>

.//here there are 48 more “sucursal”--- 50 nodes total...

    <sucursal>
        <idSuc>53</> // last sucursal
        <nombre>Abasto</nombre>
    </sucursal>
</listado>
```

…..

I need to take (in variable php) not the count of the “sucursal” or “idSuc” (in this case “50”) but the value of the last “idSuc” ( in my case “53”)... 
I don't want to set the "idSuc" as atribute of "sucursal" ( xe) because they are datums take from a form ($_POST), etc..

I'm trying with “xpath” and “lastchild”, etc... but nothing... and “length” is ok but it's not what I need.. because it's useless in my work.

for ex:

```
<?php $datos= new DOMDocument(); 
$datos->load('datos2.xml'); 
$sucs = $datos->getElementsByTagName("sucursal"); 
$id = $datos->getElementsByTagName("idSuc"); ?> .. 
?>
```

and then in the form where I need this "value":

```
<form method="POST"....> <input name="idSuc" value="<?php print_r($id->length+1)?>"..>
```

Also with:

- `value="<?php print_r($id->last_child.value+1)?>"` -- in the form --
- `$elements->xpath('listado/sucursal [last()]');` 
      and then I try to print `$elements` in the form.... nothing

And many others that I dont remember now because I remove all.. :(

Please,... somebody can help me!!.. or give just an diferent idea... ??!

thanks a lot!!... I had working with this 4 days and nothig!! :(

Comment: Post the code you tried, you could have been on the right path

Comment: What XML library are you working with ? SimpleXML? DOMDocument?

Comment: @leonhard4 - could you edit that into the question, please? It's a lot easier to read than it is in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($datos);
$lastIdSuc = $xpath->query('/listado/sucursal[last()]/idSuc')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

and

```
<input name="idSuc" value="<?php echo $lastIdSuc; ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you paul t.! It worked perfectly!
  Short and clear. As it is supposed to be, right?


And helped me better understand php syntax.
I'm pretty new to this and a page like this is a great help for people like me.
Maybe in a few days I ask again if I can not "order" the "sucursal" in the xml each time and after eliminating any intermediate ..

Thank you again! Greetings from the South! ;)

Comment: bingo, thanks for helping me withy my issue $variable->nodeValue was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should load the XML like this:

```
$datos->load('datos2.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```

This way, all blank nodes (even empty spaces) are ignored. Now, this line

```
$sucs = $datos->getElementsByTagName("sucursal");
```

gives you all the sucursal nodes as a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), so, to get the last one, you do this:

```
$last = $sucs->item($sucs->length - 1);
```

which gives you a [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) object. Now you need its children, which you can get like this:

```
$suc_children = $last->childNodes;
```

**childNodes** is another DOMNodeList. If you are sure that the element idSuc will always be the first element, then you get it using

```
$id_suc = $suc_children->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

**First** check if there are any $suc_children, otherwise you will get no ID:

```
if($suc_children->hasChildNodes())
  $id_suc = $suc_children->firstChild->nodeValue;
  // You could do $suc_children->item(0)->nodeValue too
```

If you are not sure that the first element will be idSuc, then you will have to iterate through the DOMNodeList to find it.

Comment: Thanks for answering too Skaparate! It has not worked on me, as the first answer yes. But the same has also helped me better understand the syntax of this language.
I will continue practicing ... and learning. ;)
Greetings!